# SharePoint List permission issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 with Windows Server 2008, using publishing portal template. I have a list in a page. I want to set permission to allow all authenticated (i.e. non-anonymous) user to be able to add new item to the list, but not allow them to change schema (e.g. add a new column, delete a column or create a new view for the list).

What kinds of permission should I set and how to set?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to grant contribute rights to "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users". There's an "Add all authenticated users" link when you add a new user to the list permissions.

Unless they have "Manage Lists" or similar permissions, they won't be able to alter said list.

I don't know that you can restrict personal view creation without limiting all personalization. Check out "Item-level Permissions" under your lists "Advanced Settings" for some alternatives that might suit your needs (you don't say why you want to inhibit view creation).

Comment: Cool, question answered!